# Mod Rewrite Replace Link

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need help to replace any link like :

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php/download?file=WQE875487
```

To

```
http://www.domain.com/download?file=WQE875487
```

Only if comes with:

```
index.php/download?file=
```

Need to replace it to:

```
download?file=
```

As I am using index.php for other things too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: This is not helping as like I said I am using index.php for other things too .

Only if comes with:

index.php/download?file=

Need to replace it to:

download?file=

Comment: it is always using index file, so:
http://localhost/index.php?download=file.jpg
equals
http://localhost?download=file.jpg
if you haven't changed the index-file setting in your apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule would be

```
RewriteRule index\.php/download\?file=([a-zA-Z0-9]*) download?file=$1
```

If your use index.php without the download info, it will not redirect. It will not redirect if you do not specify a file= (index.php/download will not redirect)

index.php/download?file= will work though. If you don't want it to work with empty file just change the asterix to plus sign.

```
RewriteRule index\.php/download\?file=([a-zA-Z0-9]+) download?file=$1
```

PS - I don't know if your file value can use something else than letters and numbers [a-zA-Z0-9]. Change it accordingly to your usage.